# Livereload(rebuild) Angular2 on Flask App

Tags: angular, flask, angular-cli, angular2-cli

I am new in frontend, so I have some problems with flask and angular 2 integrating. I have to create site for visualization some data, user can upload file with data, then python scripts will process them and draw some charts.
I have created new flask app, it works fine, but now I should create Angular 2 app. As I know, developing frontend in Angular is separated from backend and totally independent, but I don't want to build angular project on every change and add it to /static/, I want to have livereload like for flask app. Is it possible to have angular and flask in one directory, integrated and updated without rebooting\rebuilding.
P.S. I use angular2-cli

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, this is a good way but at least it works:

first you should define method in flask:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return send_file('static/html/index.html')
```

than I have just put todo files (html, js and css) to static directory from https://angularjs.org/

you can see more info here https://github.com/ArtyomKaltovich/test